# Error: "unrecognized arguments: shell" - OAuth 2.0 Google APIs Client for Python

Tags: python, shell, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to do a pure server side authentication. I've followed all the procedures mentioned in the code sample provided on [google developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#retrieve_my_uploads). The problem is that `execfile()` works fine in the normal `python shell` but it throws the below mentioned error in the `python interactive shell`.

Following is the log for the statements. What else needs to be defined in the `playlistitems.py` file so that it can be executed in the **Python Interactive Shell**.

Code for `playlistitems.py` : [Sample Code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#retrieve_my_uploads)

```
Kshitij:trailers_backend Kshitij$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> execfile("playlistitems.py")
usage: manage.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME] [--noauth_local_webserver]
                 [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                 [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: shell
Kshitij:trailers_backend Kshitij$
```

I passed the arguments by changing the values in the `tools.py` itself. Following is the error that I got. How do I solve it? And end to end example for this case?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Kshitij/django project/trailers_backend/videoStore/getVideos.py", line 62, in getVideos
     credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1260, in add_argument
    if not args or len(args) == 1 and args[0][0] not in chars:
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

Comment: You should also include the actual code of `playlistitems.py`, it would help us highlight what is missing in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got the working code with some help from @Stormie. So here is the working code snippet.

```
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    flags = argparser.parse_args('--auth_host_name localhost --logging_level INFO'.split())
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
```

I got to know about `parse_args()` just now. [parse_args()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) method of ArgumentParser is needed to be passed the parameters.

If you are authenticating from the command line and your browser doesn't support Javascript, you may want to add the argument --noauth_local_webserver:

```
flags = argparser.parse_args('--auth_host_name localhost --logging_level INFO --noauth_local_webserver'.split())
        credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me
from oauth2client import tools
flags = tools.argparser.parse_args([])
This prompted me to authentication url in browser.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass through arguments for your `run_flow()` method from the [`OAuth2Client tools`](https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.tools-module.html). It shows that when you call `run_flow()` you must parse the following arguments:

```
run_flow(flow, storage, flags, http=None)
```

The flags are what you are missing, you must add the flags (described in the link):

```
--auth_host_name: Host name to use when running a local web server
    to handle redirects during OAuth authorization.
    (default: 'localhost')

--auth_host_port: Port to use when running a local web server to handle
    redirects during OAuth authorization.;
    repeat this option to specify a list of values
    (default: '[8080, 8090]')
    (an integer)

--[no]auth_local_webserver: Run a local web server to handle redirects
    during OAuth authorization.
    (default: 'true')
```

I still haven't cracked how exactly to parse them unfortunately, I currently have a bountied question regarding how to emulate the old `run()` method of authenticating your session [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422545/which-flag-for-run-flow-will-simulate-the-now-deprecated-run).

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply. I've updated the `argparser` in `tools.py` with default values. (I'm not sure if I'm doing it right). Nonetheless, I got an error which I've updated in the question. Can you please help me with this end to end?

Comment: Hi, I somehow got it working. Your instructions helped. But I don't clarity as to how do I pass multiple arguments in `parse_args()`? Even [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) doesn't give an example for passing multicharacter options.