# Which flag for run_flow() will simulate the now deprecated run()

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, gmail-api, oauth2client

I am trying to authenticate my credentials to access the GMail API. Previously I did this using the [`run()`](https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.tools-module.html) method from OAuth2, and the code `credentials = tools.run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)` but this is now a deprecated method. I am now using the [`run_flow()`](https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.tools-module.html) method to authenticate my credentials.

```
import httplib2
import argparse
from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'your_client_secret.json'
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'
STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
http = httplib2.Http()
credentials = STORAGE.get()there are credentials, no reauth is needed
#parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser])
#flags = parser.parse_args()    #Put your arguments in the parenthesis
if credentials is None or credentials.access_token_expired:
    credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)
    #credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, STORAGE, flags, http=http)
http = credentials.authorize(http)
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

The **commented** lines are the code that uses `run_flow()` and not `run()`.

The commented out code gives me the error: `run.py: error: unrecognized arguments: AdminTests`, AdminTests is not an argument I give to Python.

And when I change the arguments parsed to `flags = parser.parse_args(['--noauth_local_webserver'])` I get no error, but nothing happens.

Which `flag` should I use to simulate the `run()` as closesly as possible and how should I parse it?

**Edit:** When using the `run()` method to authenticate my credentials the URL accessed is:
`http://localhost:8080/?code=4/myuniqueID` (missing my unique ID in the example)

Comment: more details can be found here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890146/how-to-get-google-analytics-credentials-without-gflags-using-run-flow-instead/25529906#25529906

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what you need to do for this is pass an empty list of args to the argparser like this

```
flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
```

Comment: This seems obsolete (at least for Python3): `tools.run_flow()` contains this code: 
    `if flags is None:`
        `flags = argparser.parse_args()`
so no need to do this by hand.

Comment: As is true with most tech, it evolves and things become obsolete. I haven't looked back at the code, but this answer was ~ 3.5 years ago and it was most definitely in python 2.7 :)

Comment: I need to update my comment: the built-in code will use the global `argv` by default and hence will work only if the global `argv` is empty or contains only arguments the built-in parser recognizes. If you have your own arguments, the built-in parser is likely to fail. Therefore your anwer is still valid and necessary.

Answer (score -1):

After comparing your code to the source code of OAuth's `run` and `run_flow`, it turns out that there is a significant difference between whether you include the `http` argument.

So,

```
tools.run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)
```

can be simulated with,

```
tools.run_flow(flow, STORAGE, flags, http=http)
```

but you have,

```
tools.run_flow(flow, STORAGE, flags)
```

Comment: You haven't even read the question properly.. Flags are arguments taken at the command line (and are given [here](https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.tools-module.html) to give directions to the storage you are using for your credentials and the method you wish to use to access/authenticate them.